# Translation of “so did”

Tags: locutions

How would I translate “so did” as in:

- When everything fell to pieces, so did her support system.

My attempts:

- Quand tout s’est effondré, aussi son système de soutien.
- Quand tout s’est effondré, ainsi son système de soutien.
- Quand tout s’est effondré, ainsi l’a fait son system de soutien.

Am I at all close?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a translation of this sentence I will say something like :

> Quand tout est tombé en morceaux, son système de soutien a fait de même.

But it could be changed depending on the context.

You can find some examples [here](https://context.reverso.net/traduction/anglais-francais/so+did)

Comment: It seems to be as simple as saying “aussi,” but I take a liking to “tout comme.” :)

Comment: @tssmith2425 "Quand tout s’est effondré, aussi son système de soutien." I think the use of "aussi" here is not correct. "tout comme" will be better as you say.

Comment: Definitely "tout comme" (if I may give my opinion)

Comment: Donc, « quand tout est tombé en morceaux, tout comme son système de soutien. » Et sans « quand » , « tout comme » se traduit donc comme « just like » en anglais.

Comment: @Maryannah I promise I value your opinion and you’re always welcome to share on my questions.

Comment: @tssmith2425 thank you <3 and to answer you, "quand tout est tombé en morceaux, tout comme son système de soutien" displays a "répétition", which is a stylistic device : you can use it, but on an everyday basis it gets annoying. I would go for the fancy "quand tout [...], [...] fît de même"

Comment: @Maryannah oh! I think I get it, it’s a repetition because her support system would’ve been included in “everything” (tout) right?

Comment: No it's really a grammatical repetition : we've been repeated ou whole youth about stylistic devices, and I don't know if you can read french, but [look at #4 here](https://www.brevetdescolleges.fr/infos/figures-de-style-brevet-de-francais.php) : the "répétition" is simply using the same word many times in a sentence, and you should avoid that (here the word being "tout")

Comment: (even if the words have different meanings, or even syntaxes, they can cause a "répétition", such as `Le ver vert va vers le verre plein`)

Comment: You taught me something new, thank you very much. :) I can read French and I understand now. Let me change the sentence a bit. Does this make sense: “quand sa relation est tombé en morceaux, tout comme son système de soutien”?

Answer (score 3):

> Tout s'est écroulé (au figuré), incluant son réseau de soutien.
>   Quand tout s'écroula, ce fut aussi le cas de son réseau de
>   soutien.
>  Quand tout s'écroula, il en fut/alla de même de son
>   réseau de soutien.
>  Quand tout s'écroula, son réseau de soutien
>   disparut par le fait même.

« *Quand tout s'est écroulé, tout comme son réseau de soutien.* », mentionné en commentaire ([1](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/36591/translation-of-so-did#comment73069_36593), [2](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/36591/translation-of-so-did#comment73075_36593)), est une phrase incomplète, voire incohérente.

Comment: Quelqu'un peut me dire si je me trompe en employant l'auxiliaire _être_ et le pronom _en_ dans le troisième exemple et s'il y a une différence d'avec _faire_ tel que présenté dans une autre [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/36593/19187) ?

Comment: I have almost zero experience with the literary past tenses, and I can make sense of your examples (which I’m proud of :) ), so I’ll maybe utilize these when I’m writing prose in French. It’ll also help me practice.

Comment: @Survenant9r7 l'utilisation du "en" ne me semble pas incorrecte